# Sphinx: How to customize domain cross-references

Tags: c++, python-sphinx, cross-reference

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set up the proper cross-referencing of the class functions, but being able to customise how the links are created with the use/display of the `.. cpp:function::` directive, so that the actual header items are the cross-references. I.e. clicking on a link to `GetItemInfo` is linked to the item I've highlighted with the mouse (in blue), not the currently generated link (in yellow).

Is this even possible?

EDIT: what I want is the items at `<--` to be the links, instead of the auto-generated text from the current `.. cpp:function::` block of links.

The below output is generated from the following:

```
Member Functions
----------------

.. cpp:function::
>>> I don't want these auto-generated links
    status_t BDeskbar::AddItem()
    status_t BDeskbar::RemoveItem()
    status_t BDeskbar::CountItems()
    status_t BDeskbar::HasItems()
    status_t BDeskbar::GetItemInfo()
<<<

### I want each of these to be the cross-referenced link targets instead
AddItem(), RemoveItem(), CountItems(), HasItem(), GetItemInfo() <--
    ::

        status_t AddItem(BView* view,
                        int32* id = NULL);
        status_t AddItem(entry_ref* addon,
                        int32* id = NULL);

    ::

        status_t RemoveItem(int32 id);
        status_t RemoveItem(const char* name);
```

An example cross-reference that works fine.

```
:cpp:function:`GetItemInfo() <BDeskbar::GetItemInfo()>` points :cpp:expr:`found_name` to the name of the
    item identified by :cpp:expr:`for_id`, or sets :cpp:expr:`found_id` of the item
    identified by :cpp:expr:`for_name`.
```

[image: current output]

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation about cross-references in the C++ domain? https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing

Comment: That's what I currently have working there, but I want to be able to customise the links as described in the post.

Comment: I don't understand. There is no explicit cross-reference markup in the RST sample.

Comment: Ah, sorry, the cross-reference itself works, but I want to handle it differently. I've updated the question to hopefully make it a bit clearer.

Comment: What is it that "works fine"? There is no role called `:cpp:function:` , but there is one called `:cpp:func:`.

Comment: There is no way to automagically link to the piece of text highlighted in blue. How would Sphinx know that it is a link target? If you want to link to something, the target of the link must either have a label or be declared as some kind of object in the domain.

Comment: Sorry, I must've meant :cpp:func:. Anyway, yes, I want to declare the text highlighted in blue to be the object  member function in the domain. Can I do that? Maybe with the replace functionality? Or would I likely need to implement my own domain loosely based on the cpp one?